# JS/Electron Read json to textarea and overwrite with change in text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, electron

I have succesfully read the json and read the variable in the textarea, in this way:

```
function additem() {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'weekplan.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
            return
        }
        let json = JSON.parse(data)
        loop(json);

    })
}

async function loop(json) {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`document.getElementById("mon1").innerHTML = '${json.mon1}'`)
}
```

In the html :

```
<textarea type="text" id="mon1" readonly="true" onblur="this.readOnly='true';" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';"></textarea>
```

How can i overwrite the variable mon1 in the json when it change in the textarea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it to work by recreating the json and updating it on any text change

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    var textareamon1 = document.getElementById('mon1');
    function updateResult() {
       m1 = textareamon1.value;
       var obj = '{'
             +'"mon1" : '+'"'+m1+'"'+','
             +'}';
       fs.writeFileSync('weekplan.json', obj);
    }
    textareamon1.onkeyup = updateResult;
```